# PHP CURL API token retrieval

Tags: php, curl

I've read everything on multiple boards and not succeeded...need the brains trust.

what i'm getting:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   preload {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

my goal:  to retrieve the OAuth token from the FQDN/api/token endpoint

i have: endpoint, username & password (no secret or key)

i can curl from the shell and get the token - i just can't get php to do it >/

my code isn't mine anymore since i was pretty sure i was the problem but here is what i'm presently attempting to utilise: (can someone point out where i'm being a muppet!)

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://FQDN/api/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"grant_type\":\"password\",\"username\": \"user@domain.com.au\",\"password\": \"userPasswd\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Content-Length: 96",
    "Accept: application/json"
  ),
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => basic
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
print_r($response);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" disagrees with the fact that you you sent JSON in the Postfields. You may have confused the server. Either switch to sending data in querystring format, or change your content type to application/json

Comment: tnku for the detail.  made the change from x-ww- to json but still have the exact same error / issue.

Comment: in that case you'd better check the API's docs to see if "password" is considered a valid value for "grant type"

Comment: What does the API documentation say? Is the grant_type password even supported there?

Comment: What does your working shell curl look like?

Comment: the API endpoint page definitely has POST /api/token from which i get the following cli which runs quite happily in a shell * grant_type password is explicitly used to get the curl cli

Comment: curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'grant_type=password&username=user%40domain.com&password=userPasswd' 'https://FQDN/api/token'

Comment: Here you're posting x-www data and not JSON so why try to post json in php?

Comment: You need to send key value pairs out of the inputs, not JSON.

Comment: key value pairs: is there an example i can reference?

Comment: I copied one of my examples into one answer. Since you're using curl_setopt_array, you have to remove the curl_setopt stuff  and just do it like you did with the other variables.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, you need to send key value pairs:

```
$data = array(
"grant_type" => "password",
"username" => "username",
"password" => "password"
)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```